# mypy error for setup with inheritance of function that depends on class function defined differently in both classes

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have a setup that looks as following:

```
from typing import TypeVar

MyType = TypeVar('MyType', bound='TestClass')

class TestClass():
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def __mul__(self, multiplicator: int) -> 'TestClass':
        return TestClass(self.number*multiplicator)

    def test_mul(self: MyType, multiplicator: int) -> MyType:
        return self*multiplicator

class InheritingClass(TestClass):

    def __mul__(self, multiplicator: int) -> 'InheritingClass':
        return InheritingClass(self.number*multiplicator+1)
```

Evaluating this with mypy returns the error `Incompatible return value type (got "TestClass", expected "MyType")` in the line `return self*multiplicator` in `TestClass.test_mul`

The goal here is to ultimately have two different objects, where one inherits the properties of the other, and have them use the same `test_mul` function while making use of a different `__mul__` function. I want to be able to call the `test_mul` function on either class, with the respective `__mul__` functions of each class being called accordingly. Is there a way to achieve that without altering the way a new instance of the own class is returned in each `__mul__` function? If not, how would an alternative look here?

Answer (score 3):

A cast to `MyType` in the `test_mul` method should work:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, cast
MyType = TypeVar('MyType', bound='TestClass')


class TestClass():
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def __mul__(self, multiplicator: int) -> 'TestClass':
        return TestClass(self.number*multiplicator)

    def test_mul(self: MyType, multiplicator: int) -> MyType:
        return cast(MyType, self*multiplicator)


class InheritingClass(TestClass):

    def __mul__(self, multiplicator: int) -> 'InheritingClass':
        return InheritingClass(self.number*multiplicator+1)

reveal_type(TestClass(5).test_mul(5))
reveal_type(InheritingClass(5).test_mul(5))
```

gives us

```py
file.py:21: note: Revealed type is "file.TestClass*"
file.py:22: note: Revealed type is "file.InheritingClass*"
```

When mypy support for it comes, using the [Self type](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0673/) (planned for 3.11, currently in `typing-extensions`) as the return annotation for the `test_mul` method should also work. The current PR that plans to add is can be found here https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/11666

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `__mul__` in `TestClass`: it should return `MyType` and use `type(self)`.

```
MyType = TypeVar('MyType', bound='TestClass')


class TestClass():

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def __mul__(self: MyType, multiplicator: int) -> MyType:
        return type(self)(self.number * multiplicator)

    def test_mul(self: MyType, multiplicator: int) -> MyType:
        x: MyType = self * multiplicator
        return x


class InheritingClass(TestClass):

    def __mul__(self, multiplicator: int) -> 'InheritingClass':
        return InheritingClass(self.number * multiplicator + 1)


tc = TestClass(1)
tcx = tc * 3
tcy = tc.test_mul(4)
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    # Mypy: Revealed type is "Tuple[TestClass*, TestClass*]"
    reveal_type((tcx, tcy))
ic = InheritingClass(2)
icx = ic * 3
icy = ic.test_mul(4)
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    # Mypy: Revealed type is "Tuple[InheritingClass, InheritingClass*]"
    reveal_type((icx, icy))
```